# Htaccess 301 Redirection Error

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webfolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

How can i redirect my url i.e.

> www.example.com/webfolder

to

> example.com/webfolder/keyword

without screwing up the above re-write?

Comment: what is keyword here ? static or var ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html it should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com
RewriteRule ^webfolder/(.*) http://example.com/webfolder/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^webfolder$ http://example.com/webfolder/ [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webfolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

index.php should be in `/webfolder/` or you will get error 500

Comment: Yes its the essential keyword i'm targeting. I will try your code

Comment: eicto, your answer leads me to 500 internal error. Just wanted to inform you.

Comment: Its ok, i might consider redirecting in coming version if any. I will preserve this thread for later use when necessary. Thanks for support.